# SQL if statement in where clause for searching database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, filtering, if-statement

I'm creating a stored procedure to return search results where some of the parameters are optional.

I want an "if statement" in my *where* clause but can't get it working. The *where* clause should filter by only the non-null parameters.

Here's the sp

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spVillaGet 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@accomodationFK int = null,
@regionFK int = null,
@arrivalDate datetime,
@numberOfNights int,
@sleeps int = null,
@priceFloor money = null,
@priceCeil money = null
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
select tblVillas.*, tblWeeklyPrices.price from tblVillas
INNER JOIN tblWeeklyPrices on tblVillas.villaId = tblWeeklyPrices.villaFK
where 
    If @accomodationFK <> null then
        accomodationTypeFK = @accomodationFK 
     @regionFK <> null Then
        And regionFK = @regionFK 
    IF @sleeps <> null Then
        And sleeps = @sleeps 
    IF @priceFloor <> null Then
        And price >= @priceFloor And price <= @priceCeil


END
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select tblVillas.*, tblWeeklyPrices.price 
from tblVillas
INNER JOIN tblWeeklyPrices on tblVillas.villaId = tblWeeklyPrices.villaFK
where (@accomodationFK IS null OR accomodationTypeFK = @accomodationFK)
  AND (@regionFK IS null or regionFK = @regionFK)
  AND (@sleeps IS null OR sleeps = @sleeps)
  AND (@priceFloor IS null OR (price BETWEEN @priceFloor And @priceCeil))
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the value in the database is not null. I want to skip that part of the where clause if null is passed in for one of the params

Comment: Why this works: if @var is null, then the whole line is true, regardless of the rest of the line (thus ignored and unfiltered). If it's not null, than the line is false *unless* ColVar=@var, thus applying the filter. I was confused the first time I read this filter style but use it everywhere now.

Comment: mancmanomyst.myopenid.com: that's what this does. I suggest making a truth table--it's not intuitive at first.

Comment: Be aware that although this technique is commonly used, it can have pitfalls especially when there are a large number of optional parameters. Do a SO search for 'parameter sniffing' and 'cached query plans'

Comment: @Mich, good point. I actually came around some timing problems when using the technique specified in the answer as the execution plans were not optimal for some parameter sets. Using "WITH RECOMPILE" option for stored procedure somehow improved performance

Comment: @Michael Haren Good answer. I would like to bring up a key point here.  Kristof mentioned he had seen better results with the "WITH RECOMPILE" option turned on.  From my experience in low latency apps this problem is due to the assumptions made in optimization.  Any time the assumptions on a method are wrong, a runtime must go back and recompile the method.  I assume MSSQL is experiencing the same issues here.  Basically by telling MSSQL that you will be recompiling you are treating it like an "exclude" method (compiler level).  You get to skip running on wrong assumptions and recompile first.

Comment: @kristof See my comment to Michael above.  I would add that any time a method risks deoptimization often exclude it with the WITH RECOMPILE option.  You will save a round of processing.  Here is a URL that states what I expected above: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-sql-servers-with-recompile-option/5662581  Basically, you are seeing a SPROC (method) that is prone to deoptimization.  Make no assumptions on these and you can trade a bit of up front processing to avoid the pitfall.  Remember, when you make assumptions on deoptimized methods it makes a ... you get the picture!

Answer (score 1):

We've used a lot of `COALESCE` here in the past for "[dynamic WHERE clauses](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause)" like you're talking about.

```
SELECT *
FROM  vehicles
WHERE ([vin]   LIKE COALESCE(@vin, [vin])     + '%' ESCAPE '\')
  AND ([year]  LIKE COALESCE(@year, [year])   + '%' ESCAPE '\')
  AND ([make]  LIKE COALESCE(@make, [make])   + '%' ESCAPE '\')
  AND ([model] LIKE COALESCE(@model, [model]) + '%' ESCAPE '\')
```

A big problem arises though when you want to optionally filter for a column that is also nullable... if the data in the column is `null` for a given row AND the user didn't enter anything to search by for that column (so the user input is also `null`), then that row **won't even show up in the results** (which, if your filters are optional, is incorrect exclusionary behavior).

In order to compensate for nullable fields, you end up having to do messier looking SQL like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM  vehicles
WHERE (([vin]   LIKE COALESCE(@vin, [vin])     + '%' ESCAPE '\')
       OR (@vin IS NULL AND [vin] IS NULL))
  AND (([year]  LIKE COALESCE(@year, [year])   + '%' ESCAPE '\')
       OR (@year IS NULL AND [year] IS NULL))
  AND (([make]  LIKE COALESCE(@make, [make])   + '%' ESCAPE '\')
       OR (@make IS NULL AND [make] IS NULL))
  AND (([model] LIKE COALESCE(@model, [model]) + '%' ESCAPE '\')
       OR (@model IS NULL AND [model] IS NULL))
```

Comment: As I recall,  That is another difference between IsNull and Coalesce... One of them (I forget which) exhibits this behavior, and the other does not...

Comment: IsNull works ok here.  Coalesce exhibits this issue.  But you can also solve it with a cast... 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IsNull or Coalesce function

```
Where accomodationTypeFK = IsNull(@accomodationFK, accomodationTypeFK)
    And regionFK = Coalesce(@regionFK,regionFK)
    And sleeps = IsNull(@sleeps,sleeps ) 
    And price Between IsNull(@priceFloor, Price) And IsNull(priceCeil, Price)
```

This does the same thing as Michael's suggestion above...

IsNull(), and Coalesce() work more or less the same way, they return the first non-Null argument in the list, except iSNull only allows 2 arguments, and Coalesce can take any number...

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Comment: Does this break the optimizer or is it smart enough to do this well? I get nervous when I see fall-through comparisons like that. Good mention, though. I use those functions a lot. Another lesser known function is NULLIF(a,b) which returns null if a and b are equal.

Comment: Not sure about optimizer.. rely on the fact that the column is alone on one side of the = operator,  so it 'should' be SARG-able.  And NullIf() is kewl too, but I don't find as much of opportunity to use it...

Comment: Ditto: Be aware that although this technique is commonly used, it can have pitfalls especially when there are a large number of optional parameters. Do a SO search for 'parameter sniffing' and 'cached query plans'

Answer (score 0):

Just so you understand, IF is procedural code in T-SQl. It canot be used in an insert/update/delete/select statement it can only be used to determine which of two statements you want to run. When you need different possibilities within a statement, you can do as above or use a CASE statement.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting your IF statement around the entire SQL statement.  That means will have one SQL statement for each condition.  That worked for me.

Comment: Agreed with Duncan. trying doing that in a stored procedure that accepts 6 params ..